# Selenium-Unable to locate element using xpath for div class

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver  in java.I neead to click a menubar. i tried various xpaths and not working. `<div class="menu-toggler sidebar-toggler"> </div>` is the element i am trying to click. I used the xpath `/html/body/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/a`.
I am fine with any option that would help me click the menu bar.Stuck here with automation.i use ngwebdriver framework so if it can be done using ngwebdriver is also fine.It would be really great if somebody could help me with this.

```
<div class="ng-scope" ng-if="loggedIn">
    <div class="page-spinner-bar hide" ng-spinner-bar="">
    <div class="ng-scope" data-ng-controller="HeaderController">
        <div class="page-header md-shadow-z-1-i navbar navbar-fixed-top ng-scope" data-ng-include="'app/main/tpl/header.html'">
            <div class="page-header navbar navbar-fixed-top ng-scope">
                <div class="page-header-inner">
                    <div class="page-logo">
                        <div class="menu-toggler sidebar-toggler"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="menu-toggler responsive-toggler" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" href="javascript:;"> </a>
                    <img class="small-logo" src="assets/img/logo_kart_small.gif">
                    <div class="top-menu">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to select <div class="menu-toggler sidebar-toggler">

Comment: try this, //div[@class='menu-toggler sidebar-toggler']

Comment: @Ab123 I tried .even that's not working

Comment: WebElement sideMenuButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath
      ("//div[@class='menu-toggler sidebar-toggler']"));
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

    actions.moveToElement(sideMenuButton).click().perform(); This is the code i am using

Comment: What do you mean not working?? Is there any exception?? And which element do you want to locate actually??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Using JavascriptExecutor  worked!!!!....Thanks a lot..You saved my day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using `By.cssSelector()` as below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

WebElement sideMenuButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.menu-toggler.sidebar-toggler")));

Actions actions = new Actions(driver); 
actions.moveToElement(sideMenuButton).click().perform();
```

**Edited** :- If unfortunately above does not work try using `JavascriptExecutor` to perform click as below :-

```
WebElement sideMenuButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.menu-toggler.sidebar-toggler")));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()",  sideMenuButton);
```

Comment: No exceptions.It just doesn't click the element.I tried the cssSelector also.My bad even that's not working

Comment: Ok try with this provided answer and let me know..;)

Comment: And do you want to click this element or hover??

Comment: If want only click no need to use `Actions`, just try as `sideMenuButton.click()`...:)

Comment: Its like a side menu bar .When i click the button at the top all the links to other page should display.when i again click it gets back to original.Just like in the mobile apps .

Comment: Then try using `sideMenuButton.click();` ..see updated answer...:)

Comment: Gaurwhen i use sideMenuButton.click() i am getting element not visible exception

Comment: Oh I see, means this element is inside any scroll bar and you want to move that element before click. Right??

Comment: If I'm right then Yes you are going absolutely right with using `Actions`, try with provided answer which will locate `a` element and click using `Actions` and let me know..:)

Comment: No the element is not inside any scroll bar.Its always visible at the top corner

Comment: Ok once try using `JavascriptExecutor` to perform click  as provided in edited answer and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try using firefox's firebug add on that has a built in xpath generator.  It's a really accurate generator.  Has solved many problems of mine even if I was using a different browser than firefox.